# Renewcommand fails after using related packages

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I've been using this code to change the appearance of references (enclosing the number within round brackets):

```
\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{(\oldref{#1})}
```

After that, I wanted to make references "clickable" so I added the package hyperref using the hidelinks option:

```
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

The links work fine but I'm wondering why the brackets are no longer visible. Obviously `hyperref` is redefining `\ref` but `\let` should update my definition too. This is independent of the order in which those instructions appear in the code. Where's the problem?

Comment: Is your redefinition inside the preamble or the document.  If I recall, `hyperref` redefines a lot of things `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What Steven B. Segletes wrote is very important: `hyperref` does really a lot of changes. The redefinition of `\ref` is not really recommended unless it is very clear what is requested

Answer (score 0):

Many redefinitions around `\ref` are delayed in `\begin{document}` (packages `hyperref`, `nameref`). Thus, the user redefinition should take place quite late, e.g. after `\begin{document}` or at the end of the preamble, delayed by `\AtBeginDocument`. Also, because of `\DeclareRobustCommand`, the redefinition is a little more complex. Package `letltxmacro` helps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\MyOldRef\ref
  \DeclareRobustCommand*{\ref}[1]{%
    (\MyOldRef{#1})%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}\label{sec:first}
Ref: \ref{sec:first}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

BTW, see package `amsmath` for `\eqref`, which adds parentheses around equation numbers.